# Скрипт на Python выдает ошибку

Tags: python-3.x, циклы

Для развлечения начал читать книжку по Python, поэтому просьба снисходительно отнестись к вопросу. Наверно, он покажется идиотски-глупым, но я не понимаю, где ошибка?
вот такой простой скрипт:

```
import os
with open(r'C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Док\Список.txt') as f:
     all_names=[i.replace('\n', '.pdf') for i in f]
     print(all_names)
names = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Док\Цветной')
print(names)
for num, i in enumerate(names):
     os.rename(i, all_names[num])
```

получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ABC/PycharmProjects/RenameFiles/Rename.py", line 18, in <module>
os.rename(i, all_names[num])
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 
'01.pdf' -> 'Иванова Лариса Ивановна.pdf'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Но ведь файлы есть! Если проверить содержание списков all_names и names, то имена существуют. Подскажите, плиз, в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указывайте полные пути к файлам.

```
old_file = os.path.join("C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Док\Цветной", i)
new_file = os.path.join("C:\Users\ABC\Documents\Док\Цветной", all_names[num])
os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```